# Marketing Cloud Contact Data Amount field comparison to journey data amount field

Tags: marketing-cloud, journeybuilder

I have a total amount field on the contact and within the journey I want to see if this total amount in coontact data DE is > than the total amount this contact has entered the journey with (journey data). Is there a way I can actually evaluate that in the decision split?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can definitely do it with [Attribute to Attribute Comparison](https://help.salesforce.com/articleView?id=sf.mc_jb_attribute_comparison.htm&type=5) within Decision Split in Journey Builder. However, take into consideration several important points:

1. Compare only attributes of the same data type (and in your case your field "Total Amount" should be number data type to have "greater than" or "less than" operators available)
2. Attributes that allow null values cannot be used in the attribute-to-attribute comparison.
3. Encrypted fields are not supported.
4. Ideally, set Contact Data on the left side of the comparison, due to this [known issue](https://trailblazer.salesforce.com/issues_view?id=a1p3A000001YomgQAC&title=attribute-to-attribute-comparison-does-not-always-work-when-contact-data-is-on-the-right-side).
5. Do not compare the same field twice within one comparison due to this [known issue](https://trailblazer.salesforce.com/issues_view?id=a1p3A0000003gU6QAI).
6. Do not forget to create an Attribute Group with the Entry Source Data Extension to be able to use it in the Decision Split later.
7. Finally, review how [contact and journey data](https://help.salesforce.com/articleView?id=sf.mc_jb_journey_contact_data.htm&type=5) works and check some official examples [here](https://help.salesforce.com/articleView?id=sf.mc_jb_data_relationships.htm&type=5) and [here](https://help.salesforce.com/articleView?id=sf.mc_jb_journey_contact_data_decision_splits.htm&type=5).

Comment: Hi Niko, I am following all that but not possible to save the decision split. However can you elaborate on what you mean in point 6? Why does the journey data need to be added to the attribute group?

Comment: Hello @Lilia, you need to create an Attribute Group with the DE from Entry Source to be able to select Contact Data and then compare it with Journey Data, which would be taken in its turn from the Entry Source DE. This way you are aligning both Datas and making it possible to compare. Please carefully revise the links in my answer.

Comment: Thank you Niko, this is the part I was missing. This means that so many journeys would require new attribute groups to be built. Do you know if there is a limit on number of attribute groups per org?

Comment: You are welcome. There is no available information about the limits. On one project we have had like 45 Attribute Groups but that is not recommended structure to follow, since Attribute Groups could be re-used. Thus better to optimize DE. If my answer helped, please select it :)

Comment: Thanks Niko, I tried selecting it but apparently I don’t have enough points to do so. One day I’ll come back and select it when I’m higher in rank here haha

Comment: Just for your knowledge, you can do it by clicking the green outlined checkmark to the left of the answer. This marks the answer as "accepted". And only from 15 reputation points, you would be able to [up-vote](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/help/privileges/vote-up) questions and answers.

Comment: Oh I see, thanks Niko!